# Python Requests response is different from chrome response

Tags: javascript, python, http, captcha

I need to download about 100 captcha images from a particular website.
My code in summary is:

1- download the page

2- search for the captcha image URL (using re) and download it

3- :( the downloaded image is different from what I'd see in browser. I guess there is a parameter in session or in the request (get or post) I need to set, which I haven't.

```
import requests
import re
import time
s = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

#download this page and look for the url of the captcha image
page = s.get('http://www.rrk.ir/News/ShowOldNews.aspx?Code=1', headers=headers)
result = re.search('img id="imgCaptcha" src="..(.*)"', page.content.decode('utf-8'))
img_url = 'http://www.rrk.ir' + result.group(1).split('"')[0]

print(img_url)
#download the image and save it to a file
img = s.get(img_url, headers=headers)
img_file_name =  './a'  + '.jpg'
with open(img_file_name, 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(img.content)

s.close()
#:( the downloaded file is different from what I see in Chrome.
```

How can I find out what setting I'm missing?

**Update 1**: As suggested, added the custom headers but it didn't help.

Comment: Send Browser-like headers along. Start with the User-Agent. Because as it is, the server will surely be able to know that it's a Python script.

Comment: Link to custom headers section docs - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

Comment: added the user-agent, didn't help :(

Answer (score 2):

Now I'm struggling with a similar problem with authorization.
If you have similar problems, you need to turn off automatic redirect in the Requests(allow_redirects=False) and check if there is a cascade of requests in the browser developer tools - perhaps the first request causes redirects between which additional parameters are generated in data/json new payload, or create new headers/cookies..

```
s = requests.Session()
resp = s.get(url_here, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
if resp.status_code == 302:
    print('Redirect!', resp.headers. resp.cookies, sep="\n")
```

Сheck cookies and response headers!
Also you can use:

```
print(resp.history)
```